# Approximation of a bivariate smooth function.

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

Let's say that $f(x, y) $ is a real valued continuous function which happens to have continuous first derivatives with respect to $x $ and $y $ and that it admits continuous second partial derivative with respect to $y $ except at most countably many points at which nevertheless it admits finite left- and right-second derivative.

Is it possible to approximate it using functions like
$$ f_n(x, y) = \sum_{k=0}^n g_{n,k}(x)h_{n,k}(y) $$

where each of $g_{n,k}(\cdot) $ is continuously differentiable and $h_{n,k} $ is continuously differentiable and twice continuously differentiable except on a countable set of points in the domain of definition where it has finite right and left-second derivatives ?

I do believe the answer to be yes, but I wonder if the conditions are straightforward. 
I am looking at this with the intent to apply it in the proof of a more general Ito-formula for Brownian motion and time without assuming that the original $f $ is twice continuously differentiable with respect to $x. $

Thank you.

Maurice

Comment: How exactly do you want to approximate? I think you can approximate any continuous two-variable function on a compact set uniformly with functions of the form $f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n f_{n,k}(x) g_{n,k}(y)$ even with smooth $f_{n,k},g_{n,k}$. This should follow from the stone Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Yes, I can use the compact thing and then get the general result via a limiting process. I forgot about the Weierstrass theorem.. Silly me. Let me try after your suggestion.